# Ubuntu Touch music file types

Tags: ubuntu-touch, music, file-format

What kind of audio file types can the Ubuntu Touch play? I want to push some of my music over, but want to make sure it works first. Can it play .mp3 file types or would I be best converting them to .ogg?

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: When it was working (a few weeks ago) it handled **.ogg** best, but also handled **.mp3**. *It did not recognise (list) Windows media files (so I converted these).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little information available on their [Music App](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/CoreApps/Music). Definitely it is a Linux system and "[y]ou can ssh to Ubuntu Touch and run any console based application" ([Ubuntu Touch FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/FAQ#Does_that_mean_that_only_Android_Devices_are_able_to_run_Ubuntu_Touch.3F)). Probably in the worst case scenario you can play the music using mpg321 :-) However, I would be *very* surprised if mp3 support was not build in.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will just give it a go. Kind of figured it would come to that. Appreciate your answer.